# Access Tuple of one contract from another

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct

I have been having problems when wanting to access information from a contract that returns it through a view function. This information is a tuple generated from a struct.

The contract code that generates such information is the following:

```
enum Grade {
    GARDEN,
    PRIMARY,
    SECONDARY,
    PREPARATORY
}

struct Student {
    uint256 generation;
    Grade grade;
    uint256 timestamp;
}

mapping(uint256 => Student) internal students;

function getStudent(uint256 _studentId) public view returns (Student memory) {
    return students[_studentId];
}
```

When accessing the information through the same contract via the **getStudent** function, it ***returns a tuple***, but the problem is how to access said information through another contract. specifically the first element of the tuple (uint256 generation).

First of all, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can access the returned tuple by assigning the returned value of your tuple returning function to a tuple of variables

```
(uint256 generation, Grade grade, uint256 timestamp) = getStudent(student_address)
```

this will create the variable generation, grade and timestamp and you can use them normally within their scope. Calling this function from another contract is exactly the same procedure.